# Who is "Sala Powell" in HoTD?

Tags: highschool-of-the-dead

In the opening and several in-episode scenes, there is a MISSING poster for "Sala Powell". These posters are in so many places, I wondered if she is somebody important. Is she?

[image]
[image]

Comment: You triggerd my intrest. Ill be devoting my next 4 hours to finding this out ^^. added a small image for other people aswell  next to the word "voice" you can see the poster.

Comment: OK, I added another above it from the intro.

Comment: Noticed in the ending credits (2nd picture), there are 3 different and differently-designed posters looking for her. There are two under the word "voice", then another outside the posted picture in the lower-left.

Comment: there is also another one more to the left were it says missing person ( blood splatterd over it). and under the one next to voice there is a small red line with numbers which resembles  the black bar of numbers to the far right bottom.

Comment: The series won't be continued so we'll never find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a devoted search all around the interwebz, I have come to a sad conclusion that I could not find anything specific about Sala Powell at all.

What I did find during my searching is some potential connections that might help others search, and some speculation.

**Potential connections**

1. This might be a reference to [Nate Powell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nate_Powell) (*not very likely*). As seen on the linked page, Nate used to be a cartoonist/writer, and also brought out a CD with W A I T called "*All The Days Are Numbered So*"; this could be a far-fetched connection.
2. This might be a reference to Chella Powell. After some research, I found out that "Sala" in some languages can be pronounced as "Chella". For Chella Powell, I found the following information quite interesting, but shamefully ended in a dead end.

   > Advances in Intelligent Systems and Computing #196 by Antonio Chella: The challenge of creating a real-life computational equivalent of the human mind ...
   >   — [source](http://powells.com/biblio/9783642342738)

   This may be far-fetched as well.

**Online speculation**

After asking quite some HotD addicts about their opinions, and looking around online myself, I found:

1. Sala Powell might be the cause of the zombie apocalypse
2. Sala Powell probably has some sort of connection to the apocalypse
3. The writer doesent even know
4. This is a plot point to be revealed

Points 1 and 2 speak for themselves. She might have been a scientist on some sort of military project. In one of the first episodes, the self defense force of Japan flies over the school, seemingly ignoring all the people flying to a specific point, picking up Sala Powell? Does she have the answer to the apocalypse? Does she have a cure? These points just give more questions than real answers and can't be really proven 'til more of the manga is released.

The 3rd point: Daisuke Satō doesn't even know himself. Satō is a writer known to go on hiatus for a long time due to having no inspiration or just writing himself into a corner not knowing how to get out of it.

And my 4th point, which seems to be most likely for now, is that this is a plot point yet to be revealed. We don't really know much about the apocalypse: not how it started, not what caused it. This might be revealed at a later point in the story. So, until Daisuke Satō makes more manga chapters to harvest information from, I don't think we can have a definite answer.

Answer (score 0):

have you thought that since Japanese people tend to say L as R and R as L, it could be that the creator intentionally named her Sala Powell instead of Sarah Power. 
Sarah Power is a Canadian actress and she resembles the drawing present in the missing poster.